# Compare two files and display difference in table form linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, redhat

I'm trying to compare the difference of two files which are a list of packages before and after an update and displaying it in a form that is easily readable.

Basically some of my contents would be like this:

Pre-update:

```
2:tar-1.23-13.el6.x86_64/
tcp_wrappers-libs-7.6-57.el6.x86_64/
14:tcpdump-4.0.0-5.20090921gitdf3cb4.2.el6.x86_64/
3:traceroute-2.0.14-2.el6.x86_64/
```

Post Update:

```
2:tar-1.23-15.el6_8.x86_64/
tcp_wrappers-libs-7.6-57.el6.x86_64/
14:tcpdump-4.0.0-5.20090921gitdf3cb4.2.el6.x86_64/
3:traceroute-2.0.14-2.el6.x86_64/
samba-common-3.6.23-43.el6_9.x86_64/
samba-winbind-clients-3.6.23-43.el6_9.x86_64/
samba-winbind-3.6.23-43.el6_9.x86_64/
```

Expected Output:

```
Pre-Update                |             Postupdate
2:tar-1.23-13.el6.x86_64/ | 2:tar-1.23-15.el6_8.x86_64/
(empty) | samba-common-3.6.23-43.el6_9.x86_64/
(empty) | samba-winbind-clients-3.6.23-43.el6_9.x86_64/
(empty) | samba-winbind-3.6.23-43.el6_9.x86_64/
```

Basically show the updates under both files and the additions only under the new file.

I don't mind other ways of displaying it as long as it nicely formatted so like oldpackagename --> newpackagename or something along that route.

Comment: Take a look at `diff` (e.g. `man diff`). It is your friend here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like nice side-by-side output, you can use:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1.txt file2.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1.txt file2.txt
2:tar-1.23-13.el6.x86_64/                 | 2:tar-1.23-15.el6_8.x86_64/
                                          > samba-common-3.6.23-43.el6_9.x86_64/
                                          > samba-winbind-clients-3.6.23-43.el6_9.x86_64/
                                          > samba-winbind-3.6.23-43.el6_9.x86_64/
```

Comment: See, you get the double benefit of having done the research and confirming your conclusion `:)` I had every faith....

Answer (score 0):

Found a very easy way to to do this with one line of code:

`echo "Pre-Upgrade                                                   |                      Post-Upgrade " > test.txt; diff -y --suppress-common-lines filea.txt fileb.txt >> test.txt`

Output:
[image]